# Show output of chef Execute in console as it runs

Tags: chef

I have the following snippet in a chef recipe:

```
chef::Log.info("Installing pips using requirements file: #{requirements_file}")
execute "pip install -E #{ve.path} -r #{requirements_file}" do
  user deploy_user
  cwd deploy_path
end
```

This installs a number of packages, and I'd like to see the output of "pip install" as chef-client is working when I invoke it via SSH. Is there any way to log the output of the execute command so that writes to the log as pip is running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking at chef to show, running it using '-l debug' which show it. Alternatively, pip can log the activity using '--log=FILENAME' option.